# When to use master-master replication VS master-slave replication

Tags: mongodb, couchdb, replication, nosql

I am using CouchDB as my noSQL database for a CRM solution.
CouchDB uses a master-master replication. 
Compared to this mongodb uses  a  master-slave replication.

Being a little newcomer to NoSQL,

> I would like to clearly understand what are the benefits of a master-master replication over master-slave replication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a master-master architecture, you can distribute the power to the places it's most needed. In a CRM, you may want a single point of authority (the head office), but authoritative content may be created by anyone (sales reps, VP's, tech support agents). Master-master let's you bring the canonical data source as close as possible to every content owner/creator in that scenario.

In master-slave architectures, everyone must be able to reach the canonical authoritative source or risk (at least) having their content overwritten or not be writable at all.

Apache CouchDB is particularly well suited to master-master replication and coupled with PouchDB can provide applications that work offline-first--cloud optional. These apps can then synchronize their changes when an Internet connection is again available.

Answer (score 0):

In master-master replication, client can both read and write on any of the instances. It has its use case where we want to independently write on two databases. Imagine you have one database in Asia and one in North America. clients in asia will write to db in asia and clients in north America will write to database in North America. This will have `low latency`

If one of the instances goes down client can write to other instances. This provides `high availability`.

In master-master replication, there is a possibility of write conflict. if you make a change on one db1 and db2 about the same time and if we are modifying the same record, when we reconcile the data between two dbs, that will result in a write conflict. But in master-slave replication, there is only one source of truth because we write ONLY ON MASTER.